# Determine if user has shared on facebook via my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I want to know if is there any way to check if the user has shared a link to my app via facebook.
I have implemented the ability to share a link to my app, and I just want to know if the user has shared it or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When user share from your app you can store user's post id.

Answer (score 0):

You can't look at a user's facebook posts without permission from the user. What would be a good idea is to, when you do create the link-sharing code, store the information that the user shared the link. Not the most ideal solution but, you know, privacy laws and stuff.